# ElasticSearch - sort search results by relevance and custom field (Date)

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I have entities with two fields - Text and Date. I want search by entities with results sorted by Date. But if I do it simply, then the result is unexpected. 
For search query "Iphone 6" there are the newest texts only with "6" in top of еру results, not with "iphone 6". Without sorting the results seem nice, but not ordered by Date as I want.
How write custom sort function which will consider both relevance and Date? Or may be exist way to give weight to field Date which will be consider in scoring?

In addition, may be I shall want to suppress search results only with "6". How to customize search to find results only by bigrams for example?

Comment: Does this solved your problem ?

Comment: No, see my comment below

Comment: hello, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 22):

Did you tried with bool query like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "field": "iphone 6"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "date": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

or with your query you can also do this with is more appropriate way of doing i guess ..

just add this as sort

```
"sort": [
        { "date":   { "order": "desc" }},
        { "_score": { "order": "desc" }}
    ]
```

all matching results sorted first by date, then by relevance.

Comment: No, unfortunately, both your suggestions don't work as I need. These queries return texts only with "6" in top of results

Comment: Atleast sort & relevance thing should work like this now there is the query part post your query here & let me see if i can help you ..

Comment: I don't need sorting first by date and then by relevance, I need sorting by scoring which based on date and relevance.

Comment: Read your question please be specific what do you want to do .

Comment: sorry it was not clear from my question.

I'd like to sort by custom function by score.

function looks like

`score = weight1 * normalized (date) + weight2 * normalized (_score)`

Comment: so you want to run a function score query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61756/discussion-between-razon-and-akash-yadav).

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to use `_score` and the `date` field both in sort. `_score` as the first sort order and `date` field as secondary sort order.

You can use simple match query to perform relevance match.

**Try it out.**

Data setup:

```
POST ecom/prod
{
    "name":"iphone 6",
    "date":"2019-02-10"
}

POST ecom/prod
{
    "name":"iphone 5",
    "date":"2019-01-10"
}

POST ecom/prod
{
    "name":"iphone 6",
    "date":"2019-02-28"
}

POST ecom/prod
{
    "name":"6",
    "date":"2019-03-01"
}
```

Query for relevance and date based sorting:

```
POST ecommerce/prododuct/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "name": "iphone 6"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
       {
          "_score": {
             "order": "desc"
          }
       },
       {
           "date": {
             "order": "desc"
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely use a [phrase matching query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html) for this.
It does position-aware matching so the documents will be considered a match for your query only if both "iphone" and "6" occur in the searched fields AND that their occurrences respects this order, "iphone" shows up before "6".

Comment: The same problem happened to me , phrase query has a strict condition that  all words must be in the document, but if  the query is allowed to  contain some extra words which not in the document , the phrase query will not work.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want to sort first by relevance and then by date. this query will do it.

```
 { "query" : {
     "match" : {
        "my_field" : "my query"   
      }
   },
  "sort": {
     "pubDate": {
        "order": "desc",
        "mode":  "min"
      }
  }
}
```

> When sorting on fields with more than one value, remember that the
> values do not have any intrinsic order; a multivalue field is just a
> bag of values. Which one do you choose to sort on? For numbers and
> dates, you can reduce a multivalue field to a single value by using
> the min, max, avg, or sum sort modes. For instance, you could sort on
> the earliest date in each dates field by using the above query.

[elasticsearch guide sorting](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html)

Comment: Sorry, this answer didn't solve the real issue asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your relevance is broken. You should use two different analyzers, 1 for setting up your index and another for searching. like this:

```
PUT /my_index/my_type/_mapping
{
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type":            "string",
                "analyzer":  "autocomplete", 
                "search_analyzer": "standard" 
            }
        }
    }
```

also you can read more about this here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html

Once you fix the relevance then sorting should work correctly.